# Visual Studio Code Extension FileSystemProvider - Nested URI stops being URI-escaped in subdirectories

Tags: uri, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write an extension that provides a virtual file system based on a single json file. Because I'm opening another workspace folder fr this, I need to include a reference to the original file in the workspace's root URI. However, vscode seems to get confused when prefixing the folder URI with the root file URI.

I have tried creating the URI manually:

```js
const rootUri = vscode.Uri.parse(`scheme:${encodeUriComponent(rootFileUri.toString())}/path`;
```

Or adding the root file URI as an authority:

```js
const rootUri = vscode.Uri.from({ scheme, authority: rootFileUri.toString(), path });
```

Both methods seem to work initially, but at some stage (after the first `readDirectory` and `stat` call), the root file URI seems to get mixed into the rest of the path:

```js
// Before

// with authority
uri = { scheme: "scheme", authority: "file:///some/file.json", path: "/" };
// with path only
uri = { scheme: "scheme", path: "file%3A%2F%2F%2Fsome%2Ffile.json/" };
```

```js
// After `accounts` subdirectory is provided
export class CustomFileSystemProvider implements FileSystemProvider {
    readDirectory(): [string, FileType][] {
        return [ ["accounts", FileType.Directory];
    }
}

// with authority
uri = { scheme: "scheme", authority: "file:", path: "///some/file.json/accounts" };
// with path only
uri = { scheme: "scheme", path: "file%3A//some/file.json/accounts" };
```

I'm fairly sure, that I have seen a `file://...` uri part in a vscode extension before, but maybe I have to include it into the URI in a different way?

I have also tried encoding the authority twice, which seems to help, but at some stage the `stat` method is called with the uri transformed to lowercase:

```js
const rootUri = vscode.Uri.from({
    scheme,
    authority: encodeUriComponent(encodeUriComponent(rootFileUri.toString())),
    path
});
```

---

### UPDATE

I did manage to use the `fragment`, tit did not get stripped away providing subdirectories. I would sill like to prepend the original URI to the path, as the positioning seems more logical to me.